# Is it possible to install Excel AddIn for all users

Tags: excel, installation, add-in

I have an xll excel Addin. 
My customers' IT people will install My Excel AddIn for every user in company and after install, they want the AddIn to be available to all users on a PC.  and they want silent installation.  Originally I thought I can add registry entry for each user. However, I find some users' entries are simply not shown up.  So this is not a solution. What else can I try? thanks

Comment: Check out [Deploying your VSTO add-ins to All Users](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia/) - it gives a lot of useful hints on how to create a setup for your desired installation.

Answer (score 1):

We do that by copying the Add-in to the xlstart folder.

On our excel 2013 on windows 64-bit  systems that  ends up at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\XLSTART
```

On excel 2016 at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\XLSTART
```

Then when any user starts excel an extra menu item shows up top "Add-ins" and your add-in can be accessed from there.